# Can you always use the Chassis as a HVAC C-wire contact point?

Tags: hvac

I am new so can't add comments to existing posts it seems, but in searching for an answer I found Tester101 suggested attaching to the chassis. I had come to the same conclusion but wasn't willing to risk it without first researching it a bit more. In the end, I did that and it works. However out of over a dozen articles about the C wire that I read it was only here that it was suggested and it happens to be about my specific brand/model. So this makes me want to ask the next logical question. Can you assume that on any unit the C (Common) wire connection can be achieved by connecting to the chassis? Or is that a unit specific solution in my case?

Comment: Can you include the link to the previous question / answer / comment you indicated?

Comment: Neutral is not ground, and transformer 24V has nothing to do with either neutral or ground.   Every transfrormer's 24V side has two terminals, which you can use for anything, but the one that isn't used for R...  is C.  ..............  If you accidentally connect the C wire to R, nothing will happen.  The smart stat will see 0 volts where it wants to see 24, which will do nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite common for the `C` terminal of HVAC transformers to be bonded to the chassis. However, using the chassis as a `C` terminal is not a common technique, and should only be used in very rare circumstances.

I'm not sure why I would have suggested that, as it's not a "proper" wiring technique.  If you can link to the question where I said that, it might shed some light on why I said it.

Comment: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/59271/add-c-wire-for-thermostat-to-goodman-furnace

Comment: @Steve I've updated the answer, to hopefully make it more clear what I wanted to say.  I didn't intend for you to connect anywhere on the chassis, I meant to connect the `C` wire where the transformer connects to the chassis (use the same screw).